# How to install cygwin additional packages?

Tags: cygwin

how to install the additional packages like gcc, gcc-objc, gcc-g++, make, patch, xorg-x11-base, xorg-x11-devel. The basic package is installed.

Comment: I have a pdf that says install the basic package by normal installation then install additional packages like gcc and others. Now i check with the command cygcheck --check-setup --dump-only as i read it somewhere. I didn't find gcc and others in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing i use setup.exe anymore for is updates and sometimes browsing for packages. Thankfully! Because "apt-cyg" is a god send! This guy over at github seems to stay on top of it, since the google code page died a long time ago. There are a few forks but this one just works great! https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg

Just use it like you would apt-get. Personally i have it switch between cygwinports mirror and standard cygwin repos. Its works splendidly well.

```
apt-cyg find gcc
apt-cyg install gcc
apt-cyg install make automake
```

It solves dependencies, is very fast and works with x86 amd x64. You can switch the mirror it uses with -m options, and then isntantly search for stuff on cygwinports. Moreover it even removes things very well with apt-get remove "package name". It describes packages you have installed and those available via your specified mirrors. If you use cygwin it really is a must.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, `Cygwin setup.exe` installer can be used non-interactively or from command line if you wish:

```
# installing custom packages
setup.exe -q -n -N -d -R c:\cygwin -s http://cygwin_mirror_you_use -l c:\packages mintty,wget,ctags,diffutils
```

where `-R` is Cygwin root installation directory, `-s` Cygwin mirror where to download new packages and `-l` where the packages are stored locally. For other options, please check [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli).

Answer (score 2):

[Download installer from the site](http://cygwin.com/install.html) and start it, choose mirror and then packages you want - setup won't break anything, it will install packages you want and update required ones as specified in GUI.

Comment: K. Im new to the software. and i don't know what is specified in GUI. But I have a pdf that says install the basic package by normal installation then install additional packages like gcc and others. Now i check with the command    cygcheck --check-setup --dump-only
as i read it somewhere. I didn't find gcc and others in that list.

Comment: just run setup.exe and follow the screens, when it will ask for packages - select gcc, gcc-objc, gcc-g++, make, patch, xorg-x11-base and xorg-x11-devel to be installed, that's all, the rest (basic) part will be installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
--categories ...
```

This works well when you want the entire contents of Base, or Admin, or any of the Software Categories installed.

Example:

```
setup-X86.exe --categories Base,Admin
```